# Vue Router scroll behavior won't scroll to id

Tags: vue-router, vue-router4

When the home page loads at path '/', both components load properly, I can scroll down manually to subhead section just fine so its there. both components have a 100vh class.  When I use an 'a' tag, it goes to the id, as it should ,  but not with the router link.

subhead is an id on a div in Subheadsection.

There is a router link in a component in HeroHeadline

Ive tried many things in the scrollBehavior function, and nothing seems to work.  There are no errors or warnings in console.

any advice would be appreciated.

**router file**

```
import {
  createRouter,
  createWebHistory,
  RouteRecordRaw,
  RouterScrollBehavior,
} from "vue-router";
import HomePage from "../pages/HomePage.vue";


const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomePage,
  },
  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)*",
    component: () => import("../pages/Error404.vue"),
  },
];
const scrollBehavior: RouterScrollBehavior = (to, from, savedPosition) => {
  if (to.hash ) {
    return { el: to.hash};
  }

  if (savedPosition) {
  
    return savedPosition;
  }
 
  console.log('else');
  
    return { left:0, top:0 };
};

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  scrollBehavior,
  routes: routes,
});

export default router;
```

**HomePage**

```
<template>
  <HeroMain />
  <SubHeadSection />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import HeroMain from "../components/hero/HeroMain.vue";
import SubHeadSection from '../components/sections/SubHeadSection.vue';
</script>
```

**HeroMain**

```
<template>
    <div class="section parallax bg1">
        <HeroHeadline />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import HeroHeadline from './HeroHeadline.vue';</script>
```

There is a router link in a component in HeroHeadline

```
<router-link to="#subhead">...</router-link>
```

The Stack

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.5",
    "@vueuse/core": "^7.5.3",
    "pinia": "^2.0.9",
    "vue": "^3.2.25",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.15",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "^2.7.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^0.29.8"
  }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I spent so much time on this, but there was a overflow-y:scroll property on the parent container of the component the router-link was in, i'm not sure why taking this off made it work , it broke something else completely unrelated, but thats another question.